# Issues parsing a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary, ios7.1

Below is a dictionary I have created by retrieving the my twitter statuses for an App Only twitter feed. I have parsed and returned the value of "text" successfully, and displayed it in a table view cell as follows:

```
static NSString *cellID =  @"FeedCell3" ;

FeedCell3 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[FeedCell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
}

NSInteger idx = indexPath.row;
NSDictionary *t = self.twitterDataSource[idx];
cell.updateLabel.text = t[@"text"];
return cell;
```

However, when I try to return other values for keys such as "profile_image_url" and "screen_name" using the method below, an (null) is returned, even though there is a value in the dictionary. What am I doing wrong?

```
cell.nameLabel.text = t[@"screen_name"];
NSURL *profileImageURL = t[@"profile_image_url"];
NSLog(@"%@", profileImageURL);
```

Dictionary Data:

```
contributors = "<null>";
        coordinates = "<null>";
        "created_at" = "Thu May 01 20:15:32 +0000 2014";
        entities =     {
            hashtags =         (
            );
            symbols =         (
            );
            urls =         (
            );
            "user_mentions" =         (
            );
        };
        "favorite_count" = 0;
        favorited = 0;
        geo = "<null>";
        id = 461962182734217473;
        "id_str" = 46398745473;
        "in_reply_to_screen_name" = "<null>";
        "in_reply_to_status_id" = "<null>";
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "<null>";
        "in_reply_to_user_id" = "<null>";
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str" = "<null>";
        lang = fr;
        place = "<null>";
        "retweet_count" = 0;
        retweeted = 0;
        source = web;
        text = "Test Tweet";
        truncated = 0;
        user =     {
            "contributors_enabled" = 0;
            "created_at" = "Sun Mar 23 21:18:10 +0000 2014";
            "default_profile" = 1;
            "default_profile_image" = 1;
            description = "";
            entities =         {
                description =             {
                    urls =                 (
                    );
                };
            };
            "favourites_count" = 0;
            "follow_request_sent" = "<null>";
            "followers_count" = 1;
            following = "<null>";
            "friends_count" = 6;
            "geo_enabled" = 0;
            id = 24072342084;
            "id_str" = 242344084;
            "is_translation_enabled" = 0;
            "is_translator" = 0;
            lang = en;
            "listed_count" = 0;
            location = "";
            name = "My Name";
            notifications = "<null>";
            "profile_background_color" = C0DEED;
            "profile_background_image_url" = "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";
            "profile_background_image_url_https" = "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";
            "profile_background_tile" = 0;
            "profile_image_url" = "http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_1_normal.png";
            "profile_image_url_https" = "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_1_normal.png";
            "profile_link_color" = 0084B4;
            "profile_sidebar_border_color" = C0DEED;
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color" = DDEEF6;
            "profile_text_color" = 333333;
            "profile_use_background_image" = 1;
            protected = 0;
            "screen_name" = ScreenName;
            "statuses_count" = 2;
            "time_zone" = "<null>";
            url = "<null>";
            "utc_offset" = "<null>";
            verified = 0;
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those latter two keys you're going for are in the user dictionary, so try

```
t[@"user"][@"screen_name"];
t[@"user"][@"profile_image_url"];
```

The second issue will appear when you solve the first.  The url is a string.  To get a proper NSURL you'll need to use an NSURL class method.

```
NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:t[@"user"][@"profile_image_url"]];
```

Comment: Receiving error: no known class method for selector 'urlWithString:'